# Strange thing With CTYPE_ALNUM

Tags: php, html

i have this strange problem with the PHP function CTYPE_ALNUM

if i do:

PHP:

```
$words="àòè";


if(ctype_alnum($words)){

   Echo "Don't work";

}else{

   Echo "Work";     

}
```

this will echo out 'Work'

BUT if i have a form and in that form i insert the letters with the grave like (à , è, ò) this will echo out 'Don't Work'

Code:

```
  <form action="" method="post"> 

    <input type="text" name="words" />
    <input type="submit" />

  </form>


 $words=$_POST['words'];

 if(isset($words)){

  if(ctype_alnum($words)){

      Echo "Don't Work";

  }else{

      Echo "Work";      

 }

}
```

If i insert into the text input the letters à or è or ò This will echo out 'Don't Work'

Comment: What does `print_r($words)` show?

Comment: it show exactly the letter that i write, if i write èèè it show èèè

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctype_alnum` is locale-dependend. That means if you're using the standard `C` locale or a common one like `en_US`, that won't match accented letters, only `[A-Za-z]`. You can try setting the locale to a language that recognizes those derivations via [`setlocale`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) (beware that the locale needs to be installed on your system, and not all systems are alike), or use a more portable solution like:

```
function ctype_alnum_portable($text) {
    return (preg_match('~^[0-9a-z]*$~iu', $text) > 0);
}
```

Comment: Alix, I believe that the regular expression you were using is not perfect. preg_math('~^[0-9a-z]*$~iu', "Lajos Árpád") will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all characters defined in the Unicode Standard, try the following code. I met false detection in Mac OSX.

```
//setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8');

for ($i = 0; $i < 0x110000; ++$i) {

    $c = utf8_chr($i);
    $number = dechex($i);
    $length = strlen($number);

    if ($i < 0x10000) {
        $number = str_repeat('0', 4 - $length).$number;
    } 

    if (ctype_alnum($c)) {
        echo 'U+'.$number.' '.$c.PHP_EOL;
    }

}
function utf8_chr($code_point) {

    if ($code_point < 0 || 0x10FFFF < $code_point || (0xD800 <= $code_point && $code_point <= 0xDFFF)) {
        return '';
    }

    if ($code_point < 0x80) {
        $hex[0] = $code_point;
        $ret = chr($hex[0]);
    } else if ($code_point < 0x800) {
        $hex[0] = 0x1C0 | $code_point >> 6;
        $hex[1] = 0x80  | $code_point & 0x3F;
        $ret = chr($hex[0]).chr($hex[1]);
    } else if ($code_point < 0x10000) {
        $hex[0] = 0xE0 | $code_point >> 12;
        $hex[1] = 0x80 | $code_point >> 6 & 0x3F;
        $hex[2] = 0x80 | $code_point & 0x3F;
        $ret = chr($hex[0]).chr($hex[1]).chr($hex[2]);
    } else  {
        $hex[0] = 0xF0 | $code_point >> 18;
        $hex[1] = 0x80 | $code_point >> 12 & 0x3F;
        $hex[2] = 0x80 | $code_point >> 6 & 0x3F;
        $hex[3] = 0x80 | $code_point & 0x3F;
        $ret = chr($hex[0]).chr($hex[1]).chr($hex[2]).chr($hex[3]);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```