# Why is ctype_alnum unhelpful in matching culture-agnostic alphanumerics?

Tags: php, regex, validation

Let's suppose that I have a text in a variable called `$text` and I want to validate it, so that it can contain spaces, underscores, dots and any letters from any languages and any digits. Since I am a total noob with regular expressions, I thought I can work-around learning it, like this:

```
if (!ctype_alnum(str_replace(".", "", str_replace(" ", "", str_replace("_", "", $text))))) {
    //invalid
}
```

This correctly considers the following inputs as valid:

- foobarloremipsum
- foobarloremipsu1m
- foobarloremi psu1m
- foobar._remi psu1m

So far, so good. But if I enter my name, Lajos Árpád, which contains non-English letters, then it is considered to be invalid.

> Returns TRUE if every character in text is either a letter or a digit,
>   FALSE otherwise.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.ctype-alnum.php).

I suppose that a setting needs to be changed to allow non-English letters, but how can I use ctype_alnum to return true if and only if `$text` contains only letters or digits in a culture-agnostic fashion?

Alternatively, I am aware that some spooky regular expression can be used to resolve the issue, including things like `\p{L}` which is nice, but I am interested to know whether it is possible using `ctype_alnum`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) with `category` set to `LC_CTYPE` and the appropriate locale for the `ctype_*` family of functions to work on non-English characters.

Note that the `locale` that you're using with `setlocale` needs to actually be installed on the system, otherwise it won't work. The best way to remedy this situatioin is to use a portable solution, given [in this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010889/271402).

Comment: Thanks, vanneto, this is actually great stuff. The other answer contains a regular expression. What does the expression of '~^[0-9a-z]*$~iu' mean?

Comment: preg_match('~^[0-9a-z]*$~iu', "LajosÁrpád") returns 0, so that regular expression should not be advised, since it fails to acknowledge non-English characters.

Comment: preg_match('/^[\pL\pN. _]+$/u', $text) seems to be the solution: \pL means letter, \pN means number, [] is some kind of pattern, u is for unicode.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution! :)